# counting function for anychart labels

Tags: anychart

I have a pie chart that I've made using anychart.js

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqqgf5r1/6/)

What I'm trying to achieve is to make the labels on the chart 'count up' when the page loads. I have a working javascript example located [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/x95hvbjp/)

Here is the code I use to make this happen

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
});
```

I just don't know how to append this to the labels on the pie chart.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to 7.12.0 you can get out of the box animation: http://jsfiddle.net/jqqgf5r1/7/

```
    chart.animation(true);
```

Comment: AHHHH awesome. Not what I was looking for for the labels but I didn't realize the pie chart had a load animation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understood right what you trying to achieve, but I hope this sample wold help
http://jsfiddle.net/jqqgf5r1/10/

```
    // update progress values in data to random values every 500ms
    setInterval(function() {
        var pointsCount = data.getRowsCount();
                for (var i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
        chart.data().set(i, 'progress', Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100));
      }
    }, 500);
```